# location data on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation

I'm trying to get the location data of an iphone in my app, but for some reason, I keep hitting `kclAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` in my `switch` block.

I've know for a fact that location services are enabled on the simulator, and my `CLLocationManager` is declared in my header file, so I know it exists.

My code is below:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    //check if this app is allowed to access geolocation
    switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus])
    {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            // do something
            NSLog(@"Status not determined");
            break;

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            //do something
            NSLog(@"Status denied");
            break;

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            //do something
            NSLog(@"Status restricted");
            break;

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            [manager startUpdatingLocation];
            CLLocation *currentCoords = [manager location];
            NSString *location = [currentCoords description];
            UIAlertView *gps = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Current Location" message:location delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [gps show];
            //getHails or getDetails();
            break;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Per [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html), `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` means "The user has not yet made a choice regarding whether this application can use location services." I've seen other sources though that claim it can occur when there is another impediment to location services, like location services being enabled for the app but not turned on on the device.

iOS will normally prompt the user if location services are turned off, or have not been enabled for the app. In addition, if the user has previously denied location services to the app but you start location services programatically anyhow, I think the user will be prompted to turn them on. Are you seeing that behavior or something different?

Just to be clear, when you say that location services are turned on, you checked both that location services are turned on globally, and that they're enabled for your specific app, correct?

When running the app in the simulator, it may help to completely delete the app from the simulator before reinstalling, so that the settings bundle will be deleted. This should reinitialize any saved state around app-level authorization of location services for your app.

Edit:

If you're not seeing the popup to prompt you to enable location services, than indeed it sounds like you're not calling `[<your location manager instance> startUpdatingLocation]`. Are you sure that's getting called?

Comment: hmm it's strange, cause i get no popup on the simulator asking me to authorize location services for this app, so i'm wondering if my code is incorrect? 

And since i'm getting no popup, i'm not getting any location data, hence my problem.

Comment: So call `[manager startUpdatingLocation];` and click "Allow".